# How to convert null values in pyspark dataframe to None?

Tags: mongodb, apache-spark, pyspark, pymongo

I have a pyspark dataframe which connects & read data from oracle database table. This dataframe has null values in some of the columns. I need to save this dataframe to a collection in mongodB.

pyspark dataframe looks something like this

| col1 | col2 | col3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | 5 | null |
| null | 6 | 'abc' |

If I write this dataframe to mongodB it is saving only col1 and col2 from 1st record to a document and col2 and col3 to another document.

But I need all the 3 columns available in the mongo document for each dataframe row. I need to convert this null values to None.

Then when If I write to mongodB I can see null value column names with value as null and type as null in mongo document.

I am using MongoDB Spark Connector for writing dataframe to mongo.

Please suggest how to convert null values to None.

Answer (score 0):

Use dataframe.fillna(valuetoreplace, subset=[list of columns to replace null values]) to replace the null values of your choice and then write the result to mongodb. If you want to limit to certain set of columns use subset in the below code.

```
df.fillna('None')
```

This command will replace your null values with None string in your dataframe but not as None object.

Comment: This command will replace Null values with 'None' string and If I write to mongodB it will be save as String type not Null type.

Comment: You can convert your spark dataframe to pandas dataframe and then replace None string with None object.

Comment: df.toPandas().astype(str).replace({'None':None})